# How to change email id in from field in outlook

Tags: vba

I need help to find  a way to change the e-mail with which email will be sent using VBA. Below is my current code and emails are being sent with my e-mail and i need to change it to group email id.

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olMail As Object
Dim olRecip As Object
Dim olAtmt As Object
Dim iRow As Long
Dim Recip As String
Dim Subject As String
Dim Atmt As String
Dim sMsgBody As String
Dim strfrom As String



iRow = 2

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Do Until IsEmpty(Sht.Cells(iRow, 1))

Recip = Sht.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
Subject = Sht.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
Atmt = Sht.Cells(iRow, 3).Value ' Attachment Path


Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

With olMail
Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
    .Subject = Subject
    .body = sMsgBody
    .Display
    .
Set olAtmt = .Attachments.Add(Atmt)

olRecip.Resolve
End With

iRow = iRow + 1

Loop

Set olApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you need to check [MailItem.Sender Property (Outlook)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the sender account, use the [Sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender) property

If you want to send it with your own account but with a different mail address, use [SentOnBehalfOfName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sentonbehalfofname) property. That's what I usually do.

```
With olMail
Set olRecip = .Recipients.Add(Recip)
    ' chose either :
    .Sender = "anything@yourcompany.com"
    ' or
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "anything@yourcompany.com"
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped